# Starting Oracle Database under Kitematic

Tags: oracle, docker, kitematic

I am starting to learn Docker.
On Docker Hub I found the Oracle Database Enterprise Edition Container which I would like to play around with.
Can I use Kitematic to controll the container? I have not seen Oracle DB in Kitematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinematic helps to seamlessly switch between Kinematic GUI or Docker CLI to run and manage your application containers.
Just install Kitematic on your system. Start any container on your system which can be your Oracle DB. 
Once the container is started, you can open kitematic and see the running containers in it.

Comment: This is absolutly correct, thank you. The container shows up in Kitematic, already with Environment Variables. Great Thing!